# What and how exactly changes the control from one current thread to next runnable thread inside "switch function" inside the kernel space code?

Tags: unix, operating-system, thread-safety, kernel

During UNIX kernel development (e.g. Weenix), there is thread_switch function. Inside this function IP enters with current executing thread and while exiting the current thread goes to sleep and the next thread in runnable queue gets awaken and leaves function with its IP. Can you please help me to understand what and how this control switch happens inside function. kernel switches the control but using what data structure and context (interrupts to switch threads?)

Comment: There are some `*.S` files at the `torvalds/linux` `GitHub` repository containing implementation of the `context switch`. Does it help?

Comment: in that case welcome to Stack Overflow. I know that it is something that can be learned by assembly-level debugging and by reading weird thick books, but I don't know how to explain it in a nowadays usable way. If you do find some easy to consume explanation (links, notes, pictures, anything) of the problem then posting your version as [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) would be welcome

Comment: High level explanation would be as follows -
This is all about storing the EBP and ESP registers. While switching the thread saves the switch function on the top of its stack and once the control is switched back to scheduler or due to any other interrupts the switch functions is evoked and the EBP and ESP is restored in the CPU to continue at same point.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, it is all about manipulation of Frame pointer and stack pointer - registers inside the CPU.
Every thread control block has a stack pointer which points to the topmost memory location of the thread's stack. For a running thread, the stack pointer is maintained in the ESP register of the CPU. For sleeping thread, the SP is maintained as a part of thread control block.

Following things occur when a thread invokes switch function to pass control to another thread.

1. Save the stack pointer in the current thread's context - This goes into Thread Control Block.
2. Place the next thread's context into current thread's context - this replaces the current thread with next thread. Context refers to the collection of the set of registers(including eip), return values, function arguments and many more things.
3. Get the value of the stack pointer from the next thread's context and load it into ESP.
4. At this point, threads are effectively switched. The function returns to the new thread.

Steps 1,2 and 3 are performed by the Weenix kernel in one atomic operation. Any interrupts are disabled before the operation and re-enabled later. This also prevents the Thread state from getting corrupt by another interrupt context.

For a thread that called switch function, it looks like the switch function never returned, and for the callee thread, it looks like the switch function just got over and is returning. So actually speaking, a thread sleeps inside the function call to switch, which will return only when some other thread calls switch.

Source: Operating Systems in depth by Thomas W. Doeppner

Note  : The above answer applies to x86 based machines. Different architectures (e.g. Spark) may have different CPU registers and thus different contexts and/or registers.

Hope this helps...